# How to connect to a target server via SSH with a key from a GitLab pipeline?

Tags: git, ssh, deployment, server, gitlab

I want to connect to a server via SSH with a public key when GitLab pipeline succeeds.

As I see, I need to generate a key with ssh-keygen on GitLab side and add it to server where I want to connect.

I can generate a key during the pipeline but as the public key is not added to the target server, it makes no sense.

I suppose it's a common scenario to connect from a CI build to a remote SSH with a key.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run ssh-keygen from wherever you want as long as you use the appropriate keys on the appropriate server.

Here is what you need:

- Generate a key pair
- Copy the **private** key to a gitlab CI variable (let's call it `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`)
- Copy the **public** key to the server gitlab will connect to and add it to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
- Tell your CI pipeline to use the private key that is stored in the Gitlab CI variable

In order to do that last step, just add the following to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the script or before_script section of the job of interest:

```
- 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
# Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
# Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

Then do your SSH connections and voilà !

EDIT: I couldn't remember where I had found this info the first time but here it is : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html

Comment: Maybe a silly question but where to generate the ssh keys? I assume you need to generate them on the target server.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the SSH keys can be generated anywhere as long as you copy the private key to a Gitlab CI variable and copy the public key file to the target server

Comment: Is this any secure? I mean, those are just variables and people are putting their entire life there, risking being exposed and/or hacked. Am I being paranoid?

Answer (score 0):

See detailed example in GitLab's CI/CD documentation -

[**Using SSH keys with GitLab CI/CD**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/)
(the example is a bit different than [*Jawad*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654146/jawad)'s example
and I'm not quoting it here on purpose as it may change in the future)

To get your public-key to the remote host, see (three) examples here:

[**How to Upload an SSH Public Key to an Existing Droplet**](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-existing-droplet/)