# How to properly deploy to host from gitlab-ci (+docker)?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## Situation

I have one server: `192.168.1.2`. This server has a `gitlab` installed on it alongside with a `docker` linked to a `gitlab-runner`. Keep in mind that we are talking about the same server.

I have a script at `/etc/cfupdate.py`, which is, you can tell, a Python script. I would like to have this file up in my repository with auto-deployment.

**Note:** The file is owned by `deploymgr`, a user created just for this purpose. It has `rw` access.

## Attempt #1

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:latest

before_script:
   - echo "Starting script exec."

after_script:
  - echo "CI Script Complete."

test-run:
 stage: build
 script:
   - echo "Setting up..."
   - pip3 install requests
   - python3 "cfupdate.py"

deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - docker cp $HOSTNAME:$PWD/cfupdate.py /etc/
 only:
   - master
```

After a quick research, docker is actually made for process and resource isolation. That's why it's impossible to access the host.

**PS:** And `docker` is a host-only command.

## Attempt #2

Running a Webhook at build finish. This is a possibly working solution, but I would like to have a better one, which can be contained in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

## Attempt #3

Given the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` (only deploy part):

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - scp 'cfupdate.py' deploymgr@192.168.1.2:/etc/
 only:
   - master
```

I tried to ssh myself to the host, and using scp, copy the file, but with no luck, as the user has a password. I don't really want to use `sshpass -p` to pass the password, although it is savable in the *Secret Variables* section of GitLab. Also tried with `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`, still needs password, and as we know, docker's SSH keys (**PS** indeed including all other files) are not saved, they are destroyed immediately upon the docker's shutdown.

## Attempt #4

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - curl --form "fileupload=@cfupdate.py" 192.168.1.2:[port]/upload.php
 only:
   - master
```

This way, (haven't really tried it) it also could work, but I'm still looking for a better way. As you can see, this is a really make-do way and if we would be talking about lots of files, this method wouldn't serve well.

Any ideas? Or any suggestions about GitLab? Maybe it has a built-in function for deployment that I don't know about?

Comment: Regarding attempt #3, I think this solves your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41494370/6654146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran through numerous docs involving docker, gitlab-ci, etc., but they didn't help me. Though, I've successfully devised a working solution:

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 before_script:
   - apt-get update
   - apt-get -y install rsync sshpass
 script:
   - echo "Deploying to staging server..."
   - "sshpass -e rsync -vvvurz --progress -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' . deploymgr@192.168.1.2:/etc/cfupdate/"
 only:
   - master
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider using [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) instead of docker executor for this particular repo so you can write plain sh script like this:

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - cp cfupdate.py /etc/cfupdate.py
    only:
        - master
```